# How can I cast an ASP.NET Label?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page. I have labels like:

```
<label id="CalistigiFirmaUnvanLabel" runat="server" style="width: 100%; float: left; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; font-family: Calibri">
Çalıştığı Kurumun Unvanı</label>
```

There are 10 of them in each 15 pages. In a condition, I want to change the innerTexts of these labels. Therefore in Page Load or Init, I want to write something like this:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in mainDiv.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl.GetType().BaseType.Equals(CalistigiFirmaUnvanLabel.GetType())
    {
        //if this labels innerText is in my Dictionary, then change it like (Label).InnerText = sth;
    }
}
```

However, the "Label" cast doesn't work. When I look at the type of `calistigifirmaVergiNoLabel`, it says it is `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl`. When I cast Label for the ctrl inside the inner if, it doesn't have a property "InnerText". How can I cast it? Also, this code takes the div's too. I only want the labels. I deleted the BaseType but then it didn't enter the if statement.

Comment: That's because a `<label>` is a `HtmlGenericControl`. If you want to use the ASP Label then declare it as `<asp:Label ID="xxx" runat="server"></asp:Label>`

Comment: can't I do it with an html label?

Comment: Yeh, use `if (ctrl is HtmlGenericControl)` then cast it to that type and then check its `InnerText`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll change the Control to HTMLGenericControl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access html labels from C# or divs for that matter too (HtmlGenericControl, or (HtmlGenericControl("label")) and type cast it to their respective types after calling findControl().  If you want to access it without the findcontrol and type cast, you need to have the 'asp' tag prefix  like:

```
<asp:Label
```

and you need to include runat="server" in the control attributes so that the code behind can access it directly. (and so it shows for you in intellisense)

Comment: I couldn't find the HTMLLabel. Right now, I am trying the HtmlGenericControl. It doesn't matter it takes the divs but I just don't want the dictionary to make a useless lookup

Comment: I'm sorry man, I forgot the label was weird, what you're looking for is: HtmlGenericControl myLabel = new HtmlGenericControl("label");

Comment: Sorry I put the wrong label here. The actual ones have the runat="server".

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `runat="server"` property with the `HtmlGenericlControl` like this:

```
<label id="CalistigiFirmaUnvanLabel" runat="server"  style="width: 100%; float: left; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; font-family: Calibri">Çalıştığı Kurumun Unvanı</label>
```

When the `runat="server"` property is applied, you can then access your label in code like this:

```
string labelText = CalistigiFirmaUnvanLabel.InnerText;
```

However, this answer assumes that each of the 10 labels on the page have different IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Label = `<asp:Label id="x" runat="server" />`

`<label>` gets translated as an HtmlGenericControl; however, you should be able to use this to figure out what the underlying tag is, check for the label tag, and process acccordingly.  Or use the server-side equivalent, so the server-side code works as you expect.

Also, them you can do:

```
if (ctrl is Label)
{
   string text = ((Label)ctrl).Text;
}
```